# Can't connect to SQL Server on virtual machine while Open VPN client is running on my system

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I've got a server where there are a few virtual machines. I use Hyper-V. I created one virtual machine and installed SQL Server 2008 R2 there.

Then I was able to connect to that server using Management Studio from every computer in the network. On one computer there is Open VPN installed. When the client is connected to that VPN one is unable to connect to SQL Server on my virtual machine, although he can connect to that machine via RDP.

If he disconnects from VPN then I'm able to connect to SQL Server using for example Management Studio.

Where should I look for explanation of this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SQL server or Hyper-V. What you're asking about is basic VPN knowledge, and it should be noted that people shouldn't be using VPN clients without knowing what they actually do.

What you're experiencing is a VPN tunnel set to stricly forward all traffic across the tunnel. Get the VPN provider to set up a split tunneling so that your internal services aren't affected by the VPN client.

[Here](http://support.vpnsecure.me/articles/frequently-asked-questions/openvpn-split-tunneling) is a guide that summarizes it.

Comment: You may be able to manually add a route that lets you see the Hyper-V install instead. This may not be an optimal solution if there is something similarly addressed at the other end of the VPN!

Comment: if I try to for example ping: 192.168.1.54 I get a response: Reply from 192.168.4.1: Destination host unreachable. quite wierd :/